# Reading and Writing Asymptote Paths to File

Tags: asymptote

I want to read/write `asymptote` `cyclic path` definitions from/to files.  For example, while running `asymptote` code, I want to build up an arbitrary `cyclic path` and write that path information to an external file for later inclusion in another `asymptote` run.

Is there already an easy solution for this?

If not, my thought is to loop thru the `path` nodes and use the `point`, `precontrol`, and `postcontrol` functions to `write` a string of the form...

```
path p = (0,0)..controls (0,100) and (100,100)..(100,0) and so on
```

to an external file and then include that file in the later `asymptote` run.  Does anyone know of an easier way?

Comment: You can get the path string extracted using `write(file, p);` where `p` is the name of the path and `file` is the file you want (e.g. `stdout` works for a quick test). Preface it with writing the string `'path p = '` and append a `';'` to get an `include`able file.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: That's perfect!  I never saw in the manual that the `write` command would work for that.  If you want to put that info in an answer I will certainly accept it.

Comment: Maybe I'll turn it into an answer this weekend. (I'm concerned about whether the `include` statement is executed at runtime or compile time; if the latter, then any changes made to the file during the current `asy` run would be omitted.) Anyway, I suspect that this version of `write` was included mainly for debugging purposes (which is also how I came across it; I was debugging and wanted to check if the "lazy" code worked before writing something more elaborate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `write` function in Asymptote accepts a `path` argument that does what you want, although this does not appear to be mentioned in the manual. Note that there seems to be no corresponding function for directly converting a `path` to a `string`, so you can't write something like `"path p = " + (string)p + ";"` where `p` is a path.

Surprisingly enough, the following example works even on the first `asy` run, which means that in essence it contains self-writing code.

```
size(5cm);

path p = (0,0) .. (1,1) .. (2,0) .. cycle;

file f = output("pathcode.asy");
write(f,"path q = ");
write(f, p);
write(f, ';');
close(f);

include "pathcode.asy";

draw(q);
write(q);  // write to command line / terminal
```

The resulting terminal output:

```
(0,0).. controls (-0.0663123,0.549145) and (0.418883,1)
 ..(1,1).. controls (1.58112,1) and (2.06631,0.549145)
 ..(2,0).. controls (1.85727,-1.18201) and (0.142734,-1.18201)
 ..cycle
```

Comment: Very nice example.  I now see in section 6.6 of the manual the following: `write(string s="", T x, suffix suffix=endl ... T[]);`  where `T` is a built-in type.